# What happened to the color in sublime text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

Something has happened so my Sublime Text 2 has no colour syntax :(

What can i do to fix this? The internet has yet to throw up an answer.

This is my settings file:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 12.0
}
```

Comment: Try using a different theme and see if that works!

Comment: I would try uninstalling and reinstalling the software then. This would be easier rather than tinkering with the settings I suppose. If you don't want to do that then check your user settings for overrides or bad syntax!

Comment: Already tried that. Unless it stores settings somewhere other than in the /Applications folder (I use OS X)?

Comment: No syntax highlighting probably isn't the color scheme, but bad syntax files (.tmLanguage). Try reverting (http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html). This will, of course, mean you have to reinstall plugins. But if you used package control, this should be trivial.

Comment: In the past I've noticed a few errors with editing the user settings (vs default settings). Try reverting your user (and default if you edited them) back to stock and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension to 'html' from 'plain text'. You can see it at right bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct. With the cursor somewhere in your code, click on the word in the bottom right-hand corner of the Sublime editor. In the pop-up list, select the language you are using, such as Python. Likely, the lack of color indicates that Plain Text had been chosen or selected by default.